# Alpine: Boot via iPXE and execute a script: can't stat "Filesystem": No such file or directory

Tags: pxe-boot, provisioning, alpine, bare-metal, ipxe

I want to execute Alpine Linux and execute a script.

alpine.ipxe

```
#!ipxe

# Unfortunately "https" will fail with current iPXE with "operation not permitted"
# https://ipxe.org/err/410de1
set base-url http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.18/releases/x86_64/netboot-3.18.4

kernel ${base-url}/vmlinuz-virt console=tty0 modules=loop,squashfs quiet nomodeset alpine_repo=https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.18/main modloop=${base-url}/modloop-virt apkovl=https://thomas-guettler.de/tmp/localhost.apkovl.tar.gz ssh_key=https://thomas-guettler.de/tmp/id_rsa.pub

initrd ${base-url}/initramfs-virt

boot
```

qemu (for testing):

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -boot n -m 4000 -hda mydisk.qcow2 -device virtio-net,netdev=n1 -netdev user,id=n1,tftp=$(pwd),bootfile=/alpine.ipxe
```

I created a simple start script:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Attention: This is busy-box shell running in Alpine Linux.
# Bash Syntax does not work here.
# This script will be started via alpine.ipxe
echo "Running startup-script.start on $(hostname) at $(date -u)"

touch /root/i-was-here
```

I created a tar.gz file and uploaded it to: https://thomas-guettler.de/tmp/localhost.apkovl.tar.gz

I see this error after running qemu:

[image: alpine-fails-to-load-apkovl]

```
df: /tmp/localhost.apkovl.tar.gz: can't find mount point
stat: can't stat "Filesystem": No such file or directory
```

What could be the reason?

If I omit the `apkovl=...` kernel parameter in the ipxe script, then Alpine boots fine.

All I want is to provision a bare metal machine: start a Linux via iPXE, then a script should call fdisk, mkfs, untar a machine image, chroot, install grub and reboot.

If a different Linux distribution is better suited for this task, please let me know.

Comment: This line might be relevant: https://github.com/alpinelinux/mkinitfs/blob/c523f72d4adb2eef8017388b96af71846b77e257/initramfs-init.in#L675
Creating `etc/.default_boot_services`  makes the boot process a bit more like without the `apkovl=...` parameter. Those two lines of errors are still present though.

Comment: @zwhconst thank you for your hint. I solved my overall goal by using Tinycore Linux. It is much smaller, and the `/opt/bootlocal.sh` runs in the foreground, so that I can see what is going on directly via the IPMI GUI.